# Can't create registration form with image uploading in Django application

Tags: django, forms

I have a problem related to registrations form. I tried to implement `One To One field`, but it didn't bring any results.

**My problems**: I can not add to the User model `ImageField` and some other fields(I'm not sure about it) and when I fill image field in the registration form I can not get the image back in the Profile page.
The only thing I want is to create a registration form with some specific additional fields and image uploading. You can also suggest other ways of realizing this.

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile-photos')
    profile_sphere = 
   models.CharField(null=True,max_length=1000,blank=True,verbose_name='Сфера деятельности', choices=(['it','Информационные технологии'],['wood','Деревообработка']))

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.profile.save()
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Profile
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm , UserChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.validators import EmailValidator

class SignUp(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Required. Inform a 
        valid email address.')
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','first_name','last_name', 'email','password1',)

class NewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('profile_sphere','bio','picture',)
```

**views.py** (def register and def profile)

```
def register(request):
    newuser = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        new = NewForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        form = SignUp(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            newuser = new.save(commit=False)
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.refresh_from_db()
            newuser.profile.image = new.get('picture')
            newuser.profile.sphere = new.cleaned_data.get('profile_sphere')
            newuser.profile.bio = new.cleaned_data.get('bio')
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accounts:login'))
    else:
        new = NewForm()
        form = SignUp()
    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html',{'form':form, 'new':new, 
        'newuser.profile.image':newuser})

def profile(request,page_number=1):
    projectobj = 
        Project.objects.filter(owner=request.user).order_by('date_added')
    current_page = Paginator(projectobj, 1)
    return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html',
    {'projectobj':current_page.page(page_number)})
```

in views in def register, i save two forms: newuser and signup form which I inherit from User model. in register function newuser = None to prevent "`variable referenced before assignment`" error.

What do I need to do?